# Проверка текста на наличие запрещенных символов JS

Tags: javascript, функции

Return true if none of the letters in the blacklist
are present in the phrase. If at least one letter from
blacklist is present in the phrase return false;

Comparison should be case insensitive. Meaning 'A' == 'a'.

Не могу понять что не так , надеюсь на вашу помощь❤

```
function hasNoneLetters(blacklist, phrase) {
  // write code here
  let p = phrase.toLowerCase();
  let b = blacklist.toLowerCase();
  let count = 0;
 for(let i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
   if(p.indexOf(b[i]) != -1){
     count += 1;
   }
 }
 if(count === b.length){
   return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function hasNoneLetters(blacklist, phrase) {
  let p = phrase.toLowerCase();
  let b = blacklist.toLowerCase();
  for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    if (p.indexOf(b[i]) != -1) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(hasNoneLetters('ZqG', 'The Walrus And The Carpenter'));
console.log(hasNoneLetters('ZwG', 'The Walrus And The Carpenter'));
```

Comment: Опять выручаешь))))

Answer (score 0):

```js
String.prototype.hasForbiddenCharacters = function(forbiddenCharacters, caseSensitive = false) {
  const text = caseSensitive ? this : this.toLowerCase();
  const characters = caseSensitive ? forbiddenCharacters : forbiddenCharacters.toLowerCase();
  return !!characters.split('').find(character => text.indexOf(character) !== -1);
}

// Регистронезависимый поиск
console.log('The Walrus And The Carpenter'.hasForbiddenCharacters('w'));
// -> true

// Регистрозависимый поиск
console.log('The Walrus And The Carpenter'.hasForbiddenCharacters('w', true));
// -> false

console.log('The Walrus And The Carpenter'.hasForbiddenCharacters('ZwG'));
// -> true

console.log('The Walrus And The Carpenter'.hasForbiddenCharacters('ZqG'));
// -> false
```